# Error while opening a different partition in ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs

I had done a dual boot by installing windows 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 in a NTFS partition. I made another separate NTFS partition for accessing files in both Ubuntu and Windows. Initially it worked normal but now am getting the below error while opening both the NTFS partitions from Ubuntu.

Error is

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/gokul/Storage: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/gokul/Storage"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

Install ntfs-3g

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

And repair

```
ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```